# Json deserialize not working in C# window 2012 servers

Tags: c#, json, rest, serialization

I am trying to deserialize the json string from Rest webserive in C#. Following is jsonstring and classes I used. But after deserialize it is giving null/empty value on server.But in local its working as expected. So what's going wrong with me?

### Json String

```
{
    "error": false,
    "parameters": [
        {
            "Programs": "ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q669;EU-PPP-O003;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-PPP-CO05;100000;pbse;EU-m110-2007;EU-zz33-L053;EU-zz21-z084;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q875;EU-zz05-L029;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-003;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-004;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-007;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-012;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-015;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-zz22-RF21;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-PPP-CO130;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q962;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q963;EU-LandR-COM;EU-01pp-O960;EU-SI-HP-INTL;G_PC_SQ;G_Survey_Inv_TPE-FY11;G_MADO_3Com;G_eLocator_AIS;G_eLocator_ATP;G_eLocator_SCE;G_eLocator_TECI;G_L&R_SCREENED;G_L&R_CASE_OPEN;EU-MDF-Tool;EU-DI-SPT-FLASHPRO;EU-DI-SPT-FLASHPRO-FY11;EU-DI-SPT-FLASHPRO-FY12;G_SPT_PCLM_Prospect;G_SPT_PCLM_Enrolled;SPEC_P1_S1_GOLD_PPS_CAN;G_SPT_Joint_Business_Planning;EU_RET_CE_SCOPE;G_PARTNER_HPQ;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-O972;SPEC_P1_SERV_SILV_CAN;SPEC_P1_STOR_SILV_CAN;SPEC_P1_NW_SILV_CAN;SPEC_P1_S1_SILV_CAN;PM_P1_PLAT_PART_CAN;PM_P1_SILV_PART_PPS_SM_CAN;SPEC_P1_WK_GOLD_CAN;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q018;"
        },
        {
            "PartnerSubTypes": "G_Tgt_Commercial_T2_Reseller_S;SSP;Supplies Commercial;"
        },
        {
            "CompanyNumber": "29682"
        },
        {
            "PartnerNameHQ": "151070026"
        },
        {
            "SiteIdentifier": "UPP"
        },
        {
            "LastName": "Isaksson"
        },
        {
            "HPInternalUser": "F"
        },
        {
            "PhysAdLine1": "?STRA HAMNEN 1"
        },
        {
            "HPPUserId": "989d35449261b4348e2f477260b1eacc"
        },
        {
            "PartnerName": "Misco AB"
        },
        {
            "PhysAdLine2": ""
        },
        {
            "PhysAdLine3": ""
        },
        {
            "PrimaryChannelSegment": "TDL"
        },
        {
            "HPOrg": "HP Sweden"
        },
        {
            "LastLoginDate": "1426841482160"
        },
        {
            "PartnerPhone": ""
        },
        {
            "PartnerLegalName": "Misco AB"
        },
        {
            "HPOrgs": "Default Organization;HP Sweden;"
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "Joakim"
        },
        {
            "CountryCode": "SE"
        },
        {
            "PreferredLanguageCode": "en"
        },
        {
            "IsPartnerAdmin": "T"
        },
        {
            "PartnerProIdHQ": "1-2GF-564"
        },
        {
            "Accreditations": "G_PM_P1_PLAT_PAR_PP_BU;G_SEGT_EG_SERV_GROWTH;G_SEGT_EG_TS_GROWTH;G_FC_AGR_T2;G_S1_Prospect;G_GPL_P1_PPS_SM;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-zz46-c103;EU-02pp-O138;G_P1_Specialist_Enrolled;G_P1_Specialist_Candidate;G_S1_EXP;G_GPL_P1_EG_BUS;G_GPL_P1_PPS;G_PM_P1_PLAT_PAR;G_PM_P1_BUS_SP_EG_BU;G_GPL_P1_WK;G_P1_Preferred_Candidate;G_P1_Specialist_Enrolled;G_S1_Candidate;G_SEGT_PAN-EG_GROWTH;G_SEGT_EG_NW_GROWTH;G_SEGT_EG_STOR_GROWTH;FY15_P1_STOR_SILV_TGT;FY15_P1_S1_SILV_TGT;FY15_P1_NW_SILV_TGT;G_GPL_P1_S1_P;G_S1_Prospect;FY15_P1_SERV_SILV_TGT;G_PM_P1_BUS_SP_EG;G_PM_P1_PLAT_PAR_PP;G_PM_P1_SILV_PAR_PP_SM;G_SPEC_P1_S1_GOLD_P;G_SPEC_P1_WK_GOLD;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-I&P;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q586;"
        },
        {
            "PhysCountry": "Sweden"
        },
        {
            "PhysCity": "LIDK?PING"
        },
        {
            "PartnerProId": "1-2GF-564"
        },
        {
            "Tier": ""
        },
        {
            "Email": "itg.itg.joakim.isaksson@misco.se"
        },
        {
            "PhysPostalCode": "531 40"
        },
        {
            "PartnerFax": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

### Rest webservice call

```
//string requestUrl = "http://localhost:8080/RestWSPartner/parameter";
                string requestUrl = "https://upp-itg-moonshot-gslb.austin.hp.com/delegate/esmtokenvalidation/v1?token="+tokenId;
                Log.WriteInfo("requestUrl in RestWS==>" + requestUrl);
                do
                {
                    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
                    request.Method = "GET";
                    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";//charset=UTF-8";

                    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(PartnerData));

                    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                    restResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(receiveStream) as PartnerData;
 Log.WriteInfo("restResponse.error ==>" + restResponse.error);
                    Log.WriteInfo("restResponse.message ==>" + restResponse.message);
                    if (restResponse.error.Equals("false"))
                    {
                       // Log.WriteInfo("restResponse===UserId>" + restResponse.parameters.HPPUserId);
                        Log.WriteInfo("restResponse===PartnerProId>" + restResponse.parameters.PreferredLanguageCode);
                        Log.WriteInfo("restResponse===PartnerProId>" + restResponse.parameters.FirstName);
                        Log.WriteInfo("success..  Break");
                        break;
                    }
```

### my class

```
namespace ProductguideNordic
{
    [DataContract]
    public class PartnerData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "error")]
        public string error { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "message")]
        public string message { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "parameters")]
        public Paramter parameters { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Paramter
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Programs")]
        public string Programs { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PartnerSubTypes")]
        public string PartnerSubTypes { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "CompanyNumber")]
        public string CompanyNumber { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PartnerNameHQ")]
        public string PartnerNameHQ { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SiteIdentifier")]
        public string SiteIdentifier { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
        public string LastName { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "HPInternalUser")]
        public string HPInternalUser { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "PhysAdLine1")]
        public string PhysAdLine1 { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "HPPUserId")]
        public string HPPUserId { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "PartnerName")]
         public string PartnerName { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "PhysAdLine2")]
        public string PhysAdLine2 { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "PhysAdLine3")]
        public string PhysAdLine3 { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "PrimaryChannelSegment")]
        public string PrimaryChannelSegment { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "HPOrg")]
        public string HPOrg { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "LastLoginDate")]
        public string LastLoginDate { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "PartnerPhone")]
        public string PartnerPhone { set; get; }

         [DataMember(Name = "PartnerLegalName")]
        public string PartnerLegalName { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "HPOrgs")]
        public string HPOrgs { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "CountryCode")]
        public string CountryCode { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PreferredLanguageCode")]
        public string PreferredLanguageCode { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "IsPartnerAdmin")]
        public string IsPartnerAdmin { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PartnerProIdHQ")]
        public string PartnerProIdHQ { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Accreditations")]
        public string Accreditations { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PhysCountry")]
        public string PhysCountry { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "physCity")]
        public string physCity { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PartnerProId")]
        public string PartnerProId { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Tier")]
        public string Tier { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PhysPostalCode")]
        public string PhysPostalCode { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PartnerFax")]
        public string PartnerFax { set; get; }

        [DataMember(Name = "PortalSessionId")]
        public string PortalSessionId { set; get; }

    }
}
```

In my local with local URL, im able to deserialize the json string and assigned to partnerdata. In server (windows 2012) after deployed into IIS(8.5)  parameters values are null/ empty and there was no error while deserialize . Rest WS sending expected response's. and restResponse.error this value deserialized correctly but parameters are not deserialized. 
So what's going wrong with me?

Comment: How attached are you to `DataContractJsonSerializer`?  Willing to use Json.NET instead?

Comment: By the way, you should wrap all of your disposables like `receiveStream`, and `response` in [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements.

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON string you show, `"parameters"` is an *array* of name/value pairs:

> ```
> {
>     "error": false,
>     "parameters": [
>         {
>             "Programs": "ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q669;EU-PPP-O003;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-PPP-CO05;100000;pbse;EU-m110-2007;EU-zz33-L053;EU-zz21-z084;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q875;EU-zz05-L029;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-003;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-004;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-007;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-012;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-015;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-zz22-RF21;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-PPP-CO130;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q962;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q963;EU-LandR-COM;EU-01pp-O960;EU-SI-HP-INTL;G_PC_SQ;G_Survey_Inv_TPE-FY11;G_MADO_3Com;G_eLocator_AIS;G_eLocator_ATP;G_eLocator_SCE;G_eLocator_TECI;G_L&R_SCREENED;G_L&R_CASE_OPEN;EU-MDF-Tool;EU-DI-SPT-FLASHPRO;EU-DI-SPT-FLASHPRO-FY11;EU-DI-SPT-FLASHPRO-FY12;G_SPT_PCLM_Prospect;G_SPT_PCLM_Enrolled;SPEC_P1_S1_GOLD_PPS_CAN;G_SPT_Joint_Business_Planning;EU_RET_CE_SCOPE;G_PARTNER_HPQ;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-O972;SPEC_P1_SERV_SILV_CAN;SPEC_P1_STOR_SILV_CAN;SPEC_P1_NW_SILV_CAN;SPEC_P1_S1_SILV_CAN;PM_P1_PLAT_PART_CAN;PM_P1_SILV_PART_PPS_SM_CAN;SPEC_P1_WK_GOLD_CAN;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q018;"
>         },
>         {
>             "PartnerSubTypes": "G_Tgt_Commercial_T2_Reseller_S;SSP;Supplies Commercial;"
>         },
> ```

Your code is attempting to deserialize parameters as a *single object* with many properties, e.g.:

> ```
> {
>     "error": false,
>     "parameters": {
>         "Programs": "ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q669;EU-PPP-O003;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-PPP-CO05;100000;pbse;EU-m110-2007;EU-zz33-L053;EU-zz21-z084;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q875;EU-zz05-L029;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-003;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-004;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-007;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-012;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-RAD-015;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-zz22-RF21;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-PPP-CO130;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q962;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q963;EU-LandR-COM;EU-01pp-O960;EU-SI-HP-INTL;G_PC_SQ;G_Survey_Inv_TPE-FY11;G_MADO_3Com;G_eLocator_AIS;G_eLocator_ATP;G_eLocator_SCE;G_eLocator_TECI;G_L&R_SCREENED;G_L&R_CASE_OPEN;EU-MDF-Tool;EU-DI-SPT-FLASHPRO;EU-DI-SPT-FLASHPRO-FY11;EU-DI-SPT-FLASHPRO-FY12;G_SPT_PCLM_Prospect;G_SPT_PCLM_Enrolled;SPEC_P1_S1_GOLD_PPS_CAN;G_SPT_Joint_Business_Planning;EU_RET_CE_SCOPE;G_PARTNER_HPQ;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-O972;SPEC_P1_SERV_SILV_CAN;SPEC_P1_STOR_SILV_CAN;SPEC_P1_NW_SILV_CAN;SPEC_P1_S1_SILV_CAN;PM_P1_PLAT_PART_CAN;PM_P1_SILV_PART_PPS_SM_CAN;SPEC_P1_WK_GOLD_CAN;ZZ_UNUSED_EU-01pp-Q018;"
>         "PartnerSubTypes": ""G_Tgt_Commercial_T2_Reseller_S;SSP;Supplies Commercial;""
> ```

In other words, the JSON you are receiving for `"parameters"`corresponds to a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` with [`UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = false`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.usesimpledictionaryformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), rather than a single POCO with various properties.

**Update**

Given that this is a legacy application using an older version of .Net (possibly with some configuration issues, as the `var` keyword is causing you to have a compiler error), I am going to suggest switching to [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which is also a built-in .Net component.  Change your data model as follows:

```
public class PartnerDataDictionary
{
    public PartnerDataDictionary()
    {
        this.ParameterDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    string _error;

    public string error { get { return _error; } set { _error = value; } }

    string _message;

    public string message { get { return _message; } set { _message = value; } }

    [System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, string> ParameterDictionary { get; set; }

    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> parameters
    {
        get
        {
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> dictList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in ParameterDictionary)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> subDict = new Dictionary<string,string>(1);
                subDict[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
                dictList.Add(subDict);
            }
            return dictList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                ParameterDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                return;
            }
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (Dictionary<string, string> entry in value)
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in entry)
                    dict.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            ParameterDictionary = dict;
        }
    }

    public string GetParameter(string key)
    {
        string value;
        if (ParameterDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            return value;
        return null;
    }

    public void SetParameter(string key, string value)
    {
        ParameterDictionary[key] = value;
    }

    // Add other properties as needed, marking them as `ScriptIgnore`:
    [System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnore]
    public string Programs
    {
        get { return GetParameter("Programs"); }
        set { SetParameter("Programs", value); }
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is reading the JSON as a list of dictionaries, then combining them into a dictionary in the setter for ease of use.

Then you can read and write your JSON parameters as follows:

```
        PartnerDataDictionary data = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<PartnerDataDictionary>(json);

        string programs = data.Programs;
        Debug.WriteLine(programs);
```

**Original Answer**

You could simply change your `PartnerData` class to have such a list of dictionaries.  If you want to continue to use your current data model, and also use `DataContractJsonSerializer`, you are going to need to introduce a [data contract surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do the conversion:

```
public class ObjectToPropertyDictionaryArraySurrogate<T> : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    class ListDictionaryArray : List<Dictionary<string, string>>
    {
    }

    #region IDataContractSurrogate Members

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(T))
            return typeof(ListDictionaryArray);
        return type;
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj is ListDictionaryArray)
        {
            var array = (ListDictionaryArray)obj;
            var dict = array.SelectMany(pair => pair).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
            var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);

            return DataContractJsonSerializerHelper.GetObject<T>(json, new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true });
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            var json = DataContractJsonSerializerHelper.GetJson((T)obj, new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true });
            var dict = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
            var array = new ListDictionaryArray();
            array.AddRange(dict.Select(pair => new[] { pair }.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)));
            return array;
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class DataContractJsonSerializerHelper
{
    public static string GetJson<T>(T obj, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(memory, obj);
            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetJson<T>(T obj)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return GetJson(obj, serializer);
    }

    public static string GetJson<T>(T obj, DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType(), settings);
        return GetJson<T>(obj, serializer);
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(string json, DataContractJsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(json))
        {
            var obj = serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            return (T)obj;
        }
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(string json)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return GetObject<T>(json, serializer);
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(string json, DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), settings);
        return GetObject<T>(json, serializer);
    }

    private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
    {
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
        var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
        {
            UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true,
            DataContractSurrogate = new ObjectToPropertyDictionaryArraySurrogate<Paramter>(),
        };
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(PartnerData), settings);
```